# Laravel banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Fala galera blz gostaria se é possível configurar no arquivo .env do laravel, colocar dados de um banco de dados que está no firebase e trabalhar localmente no projeto?

Answer (score 0):

O laravel por default não suporta conexões com o firebase, não é igual fazemos a conexão pelos drivers do próprio laravel para mysql por exemplo.
Aconselho que utilize o pacote "kreait/firebase-php" (https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), com ele você conseguirá fazer a conexão com o firebase e trabalhar normalmente. Na própria documentação te ensina um passo a passo para configurar.